# How to use Fluent Assertions Should().Throw() with NOT hardcoded exception type?

Tags: reflection, fluent-assertions

I would like to use fluent assertions `.Should().Throw`, but do not want to hardcode the type of the expected exception, instead I want it parametrized, so it is in a variable which type is Type.

Without parametrized it should be the following:

```
Action act = () => sut.MyMethod();
act.Should().Throw<MyException>().Where(myPredicate);
```

However I would like to the type of MyException to be a parameter in a variable

Answer (score 2):

FluentAssertion's API is generation. So, currently you must provide at least the base class of all exception: `Exception`.
Then, you can validate the type using `BeOfType`.

```
act.Should().Throw<Exception>().Which.Should().BeOfType(typeof(MyException));
```

Comment: @g.pickardou, would be great if you accept the answer if it is the solution for your problem!